# Creating barcode images

Tags: barcode, html-email

I need to send emails out to several thousand customers with a unique barcode present so they can redeem it either instore or online.

We have a list of coupon/barcode codes to use and have a way to dynamically pull these codes into the email so a customer will see a unique code. The problem is I need to somehow generate several thousand barcode images that are created using the unique codes. How can I solve this?

This would be perfect if our email marketing company had this functionality but unfortunately they don't:
http://www.emaildirect.com/blog/2011/11/create-unique-barcodes-with-emaildirect/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

I have found my answer!

By using the barcode generator www.barcodesinc.com I generated a URL and input this into my email.

Eg: http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=999999999&style=197&type=C128B&width=200&height=50&xres=1&font=3

I then changed the 999999999 in the URL to my conditional code to change to the specific code for that person and also bring back the barcode image for that code too!

Comment: Does your application require QR Code? What is the format of your data?

Comment: No I don't think a QR code is required. Just the barcode as this will be scanned in stores or redeemed online using the barcode number present underneath.

Comment: Your are genius! (+1) If you post your own solution as an answer I will upvote it.

Comment: Tis done @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found my answer!

By using the barcode generator www.barcodesinc.com I generated a URL and input this into my email.

Eg: http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=999999999&style=197&type=C128B&width=200&height=50&xres=1&font=3

I then changed the 999999999 in the URL to my conditional code to change to the specific code for that person and also bring back the barcode image for that code too!

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="http://qrfree.kaywa.com/?s=8&d=your+text+here" alt="QRCode"/>
```

OR

http://qrfree.kaywa.com/?s=8&d=your+text+here

Comment: Thanks for your note but this looks like a one off QR code generator whereas I have several hundred thousand barcodes to generate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this and haven't touched html but you could serialize each image and follow this example [that has some sample code on QR code](http://www.dotnetutorial.com/display-code.aspx?id=19) given a string.

```
Imports ThoughtWorks.QRCode.Codec

Dim objQRCode As QRCodeEncoder = New QRCodeEncoder()
    Dim imgImage As Image
    Dim objBitmap As Bitmap

    objQRCode.QRCodeEncodeMode = QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE
    objQRCode.QRCodeScale = 2
    objQRCode.QRCodeVersion = 5
    objQRCode.QRCodeErrorCorrect = ThoughtWorks.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.L
    imgImage = objQRCode.Encode("Test Data")
    objBitmap = New Bitmap(imgImage)
    objBitmap.Save("C:\QRCode.jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks for this but ufortunately our till systems cannot accept QR codes so I have to use barcodes.

Comment: The concept is still the same. You'd have to serialize the image and work that with that string to generate a barcode. I'm sure there are barcode libraries out there that work on this premise.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try getting in touch with http://www.linktagger.com and ask if they can help. They provide Enterprise type services for the city where I live on maps and bus terminals so it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example to generate barcode for the array of barcodes.We can 
retrieve thousands of barcodes from csv file  using pandas as well.
This example calls API and save the response in image(.png format) obtained as response from API call.

import shutil

import requests

data = [11111111111, 22222222222222222, 33333333333333, 4444444444444]

url = 'https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator_files/' + 'image.php?'

for d in data:
    params = {

```
    'code': d,
    'style': '197',
    'type': 'C128B',
    'width': '200',
    'height': '50',
    'xres': '1',
    'font': '3',
}
    response = requests.get(url, params, stream=True)
    with open('image-%s.png' % d, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
    del response
```